# Syntax error on Eclipse (public static variables)

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, syntax, global

I'm new in Java, I'm using the eclipse IDE and when trying to create a public static int I reicive a syntax error telling me to put `;`. I only receive this error when I'm initializing the variable. The other 2 variables are well used in the main class and are global variables. I get the syntax error in the `public static int classaverage` part.

Here is the code:

```
public class Calcpromedio {

    public static int classaverage;

    classaverage = valusers / numuser;  

}
```

I dont know if they're specific rules when using a global variable, so if you find out the solution, please tell me why and if there are any rules.

Thank you

I hope someday I could answer questions and not get answered questions...

Comment: Hi @Antonio Gonzalez, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark against that answer. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: [How to accept](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the line:

```
classaverage = valusers / numuser;
```

This expression is outside of all methods and code blocks. You can instead reassign it to:

```
public static int classaverage = valusers / numuser;
```

Or use a static block,

```
public static int classaverage;

static {
    classaverage = valusers / numuser;
}
```

Both of these values will be calculated when the class is loaded - static initialization. This might not be the intended behavior.

---

But just based off of the names alone, this seems like a calculation that is dependent on more data than what will be available during static initialization. I'd recommend moving that assignment into a method after all the data is available and collected.

```
public void provideData(int[] someData){
    //... Somewhere classaverage's value should be updated
    classaverage =  valusers / numuser;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second line `classaverage = valusers / numuser;` should be in a *static block / method / constructor*.